# Installing pygame 2.7 fro mac

Tags: python, installation, pygame

Im trying to install pygames 2.7 on my mac OSX (i have given up trying to get 3.3 or 3.2) But the http://www.pygame.org/ link is broken

[image]

and it is unclear which supports pygame 2.7.  Anyone one know where i can get the installation of pygame 2.7 for mac from?

just out of intrest if i still want to develop on python 3.3.2, whats the most compatible pygame i could get on my mac for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They had a hard drive crash. This is nothing about programming...

They even provided an alternative link: http://pygame.org/ftp/

Comment: Which version do i download?

Comment: That's not a right question... You can download any version that would suite your demands. But what are you trying to do?

Comment: I aim to program a couple of games, good quality games. and produce my own extension(library) of pygames.

Answer (score 0):

[Here is the downloads page](http://www.pygame.org/ftp/) as the website is down. And yes, Pygame supports 3.x.

Comment: any version of pygame supports 3.x?

Comment: Which one should i download though? Which version?

Comment: You should probably install from source on OSX for Pygame on 3.x. See https://bitbucket.org/pygame/pygame/src.

Comment: The one I just gave. There isn't a precompiled binary for Pygame 3 on OSX AFAICT, so [install from source](https://bitbucket.org/pygame/pygame/src).

Comment: for now, ive installed pgame 2.7 but its not importing

Comment: You installed Pygame 1.9 for Python 2.7. Obviously it won't import in Python 3 because it installed for Python 2. // How did you install it and what did you test with.

Comment: i have python 2.7 installed on my mac. i run IDLE to run python 2 and IDLE 3 to run python 3. check here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19068179/installation-of-pygame