# Installation of pygame

Tags: python, pygame

Okay so ive spent over 6 hours trying to do this!

I have installed python 2.7 and python 3.3. I can only get pygames 2.7 on my mac OSX. I have downloaded

```
pygame-1.9.2pre-py2.7-macosx10.7.mpkg.zip
```

From

> http://www.pygame.org/ftp/

but when i try to

> import pygame

in IDLE i get the following error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>    File "", line 1, in
>   
>     import pygame ImportError: No module named pygame

**EDIT*****When i download the pygames zip, where do i extract it? Does it matter where it is, so if it is in the downloads folder is that still okay?

Thanks for anyhelp!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you run pygame.py at any time? Python has no way of knowing what you want to load when you import pygame. It could be your script, it could be the installed package—they both have the same name.

```
Rename your script to mygame.py.
Delete any other files in the same directory as your script named pygame.py.
```

(You don't need reinstall).

Comment: So it doesnt matter where the file pygame-1.9.2pre-py2.7-macosx10.7.mpkg.zip is installed? its currently in my downloads folder

Comment: You havent answered my question

Comment: Haven't you already installed it?

Comment: i have, read my edit above

Comment: OK in the installation folder, change the name to mygame.py, and give it a whirl. (import pygame)

Comment: ohhh so i change the name of the `pygame-1.9.2pre-py2.7-macosx10.7.mpkg.zip` to mygame.py? and on a macOX where is the installation folder (im new to a mac :'( )

Comment: no, the installation files are within the zip... you extract it, instal the package, and then run import pygame, I don't know that my solution is right, but after you isntal it, change the name of the pygame.py whereever it isntals to, to mygame.py, then try importing pygame again.