# How do I run Pygame on Pycharm

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame, pycharm, failed-installation

I am trying to run pygame on the PyCharm IDE, I have installed the latest version of pygame for python 3.5 and have added it to the project interpreter. I installed pygame from http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#pygame and copied it too `python35-32/Scripts/`. The test program below runs fine in the python shell but I want to run it from PyCharm.

I have been trying to solve this for the past hour and I've hit a wall.
When I run this simple test program to see if pygame is working:

```
import pygame

pygame.init()
pygame.display.set_mode((800, 800))
```

I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last): 
  File "C:/Users/jerem/PycharmProjects/Games/hello_pygame.py", line 1, in <module>
    import pygame
  File "C:\Users\jerem\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python35\site-packages\pygame\__init__.py", line 141, in <module>
    from pygame.base import *
ImportError: No module named 'pygame.base'
```

Any help would be greatly appreiciated!
Thanks again, 
JC

Comment: It would help a lot if you told us how you installed it.

Answer (score 0):

Follow the instructions provided here. I think its related to the problem you are having on pygame and PyCharm on windows. 
[How do I download Pygame for Python 3.5.1?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35609592/how-do-i-download-pygame-for-python-3-5-1)

Answer (score 0):

its bcus pycharme has not recognised you're env or working on wrong  env
[image: here how it looks like]

https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/creating-virtual-environment.html
check this

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33315400)